# Create an image puzzle game using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to create a image puzzle game using jquery. using this code

```
var img_one=$("img[src$='one.jpg'][name='a']");

var atrval_one=img_one.attr("src");
var img_two=$("img[src$='blank.jpg'][name='b']");
    
var atrval_two=img_two.attr("src");


$('#one').click(function() 
{ 
    if(atrval_two ==  "images/img/blank.jpg"){
       $("img", '#one').attr("src", atrval_nine);
       $("img", '#two').attr("src", "images/img/one.jpg");
    }
});
```

and HTML

```
<div id="one" class="1"  style="background-repeat:no-repeat;position:absolute;"><img id="1" name="a" src="images/img/one.jpg" /></div>
<div id="two"  class="2" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; position:absolute;"><img id="2" name="b" src="images/img/blank.jpg" /></div>
```

it is a sample code. i have 9 divs and it's a 3/3 arrangement. my problem is when i click on the nearest div of the blank image it only change the image so please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Can you post more code please or a link to a jsfiddle.com example?  Or clarify what problem you're having with this code?

Comment: This code given above does not deal with 9 divs. There are only 2 divs here. It would be great if you can recreate the `situation` in its entirety

Comment: @robrich  the problem is i can't change the attribute value of the div. it only change the background image. so i want to change the attribute value of the image when i click the div please help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use  any thing you can make it in a simple jquery or js i am sending you this type of game in my answer just check it and make like that one. It is simple 0-9 puzzle game keep your images at the place of numbers change it with your images as a background images of buttons. gud luk

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>AnupPuzzle</title>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
.main-container{background:#600; width:270px; height:270px; text-align:center;}
button{width:80px; height:80px; background:#CCC; float:left; margin:5px; color:#600; font-size:18px; }
button:hover{background:#9CF;}
span{width:100%; color:#900; font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Are you want to try your brain logics...</h3>
<div class="main-container">    
    <button alt="" name="1" value="1" id="1">5</button>
    <button alt="" name="2" value="2" id="2">6</button>
    <button alt="" name="3" value="3" id="3">8</button>
    <button alt="" name="4" value="4" id="4">3</button>
    <button alt="" name="5" value="5" id="5"></button>
    <button alt="" name="6" value="6" id="6">7</button>
    <button alt="" name="7" value="7" id="7">1</button>
    <button alt="" name="8" value="8" id="8">2</button>
    <button alt="" name="9" value="9" id="9">4</button>
</div>
<span>Anup</span>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var upval, downval, leftval, rightval, txt, bVal;
$("button").click(function(){
    txt = $(this).text();
    bVal = $(this).val();   
    if(txt != ""){
        if((bVal != 1) && (bVal != 2) &&(bVal != 3)){
            upval = eval(eval(bVal)-eval(3));           
            var upTxt = $("#"+upval).text();            
            if(upTxt == ""){            
                $("#"+upval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
            }
        }
        if((bVal != 7) && (bVal != 8) &&(bVal != 9)){
            downval = eval(eval(bVal)+ eval(3));            
            var downTxt = $("#"+downval).text();
            if(downTxt == ""){          
                $("#"+downval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
            }
        }
        if((bVal != 1) && (bVal != 4) &&(bVal != 7)){
            leftval = eval(eval(bVal)-eval(1));         
            var leftTxt = $("#"+leftval).text();
            if(leftTxt == ""){          
                $("#"+leftval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
            }
        }
        if((bVal != 3) && (bVal != 6) &&(bVal != 9)){
            rightval = eval(eval(bVal)+ eval(1));           
            var rightTxt = $("#"+rightval).text();          
            if(rightTxt == ""){                 
                $("#"+rightval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
            }
        }
        var one = $("#1").text();
        var two = $("#2").text();
        var three = $("#3").text();
        var four = $("#4").text();
        var five = $("#5").text();
        var six = $("#6").text();
        var seven = $("#7").text();
        var eight = $("#8").text();
        var nine = $("#9").text();

        if((one == "1")&&(two == "2")&&(three == "3")&&(four == "4")&&(five == "5")&&(six == "6")&&(seven == "7")&&(eight == "8")&&(nine == "")){           
            alert("Congratulations You Won The Game...");
            $("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }               
    }   
});

});


</script>
```

It is full puzzle game code with css,js and html.

Comment: @Anup Does this mean you apply it like this ? <button alt="" name="1" value="1" id="1"><img src="myimg.png" alt=""></button>

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go:

```
$("#one").attr("player","one");
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as given by @Anup . Just modified it with backround button set as image. Just copy and paste this code and don't forget to download jquery-1.8.2.min.js from following link http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Puzzle</title>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
.main-container{background:#fff; width:950px; height:950px; text-align:center;}
button{width:300px; height:228px; background:#CCC; float:left; margin:0px; color:#fff; font-size:18px; }
button:hover{background:#9CF;}
span{width:100%; color:#900; font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Image Puzzle...</h3>
<div class="main-container">    
    <button alt="" name="1" value="1" id="1" style="background: url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_01.jpg) no-repeat;">1</button>
    <button alt="" name="2" value="2" id="2" style="background: url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_02.jpg) no-repeat;">2</button>
    <button alt="" name="3" value="3" id="3" style="background: url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_03.jpg) no-repeat;">3</button>
    <button alt="" name="4" value="4" id="4" style="background: url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_04.jpg) no-repeat;">4</button>
    <button alt="" name="5" value="5" id="5" style="background: url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_05.jpg) no-repeat;">5</button>
    <button alt="" name="6" value="6" id="6" style="background: url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_06.jpg) no-repeat;">6</button>
    <button alt="" name="7" value="7" id="7" style="background: url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_07.jpg) no-repeat;">7</button>
    <button alt="" name="8" value="8" id="8"></button>
    <button alt="" name="9" value="9" id="9" style="background: url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_08.jpg) no-repeat;">8</button>
</div>
<span>TEST</span>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var upval, downval, leftval, rightval, txt, bVal;
$("button").click(function(){
    txt = $(this).text();
    bVal = $(this).val();   
    if(txt != ""){
        if((bVal != 1) && (bVal != 2) &&(bVal != 3)){
            upval = eval(eval(bVal)-eval(3));           
            console.log(bVal+'- 3 = '+upval);
            var upTxt = $("#"+upval).text();
            if(upTxt == ""){            
                $("#"+upval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
                $(this).css({'background': ''});
                $("#"+upval).css({'background': 'url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_0'+txt+'.jpg)'});
            }
        }
        if((bVal != 7) && (bVal != 8) &&(bVal != 9)){
            downval = eval(eval(bVal)+ eval(3));            
            console.log(bVal+'+3 = '+downval);
            var downTxt = $("#"+downval).text();
            if(downTxt == ""){          
                $("#"+downval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
                $(this).css({'background': ''});
                $("#"+downval).css({'background': 'url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_0'+txt+'.jpg)'});
            }
        }
        if((bVal != 1) && (bVal != 4) &&(bVal != 7)){
            leftval = eval(eval(bVal)-eval(1)); 
            console.log(bVal+'-1 = '+leftval);        
            var leftTxt = $("#"+leftval).text();
            if(leftTxt == ""){          
                $("#"+leftval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
                $(this).css({'background': ''});
                $("#"+leftval).css({'background': 'url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_0'+txt+'.jpg)'});
            }
        }
        if((bVal != 3) && (bVal != 6) &&(bVal != 9)){
            rightval = eval(eval(bVal)+ eval(1));
            console.log(bVal+'+1 = '+rightval);           
            var rightTxt = $("#"+rightval).text();          
            if(rightTxt == ""){                 
                $("#"+rightval).text(txt);
                $(this).text("");
                $(this).css({'background': ''});
                $("#"+rightval).css({'background': 'url(dahlia-red-blossom-bloom-60597_0'+txt+'.jpg)'});
            }
        }
        var one = $("#1").text();
        var two = $("#2").text();
        var three = $("#3").text();
        var four = $("#4").text();
        var five = $("#5").text();
        var six = $("#6").text();
        var seven = $("#7").text();
        var eight = $("#8").text();
        var nine = $("#9").text();

        if((one == "1")&&(two == "2")&&(three == "3")&&(four == "4")&&(five == "5")&&(six == "6")&&(seven == "7")&&(eight == "8")&&(nine == "")){           
            alert("Success");
            $("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }               
    }   
});

});


</script>
```

Hope this answer will help too!